# PIVOT of non existing key value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, azure-databricks

I have a table

```
test_table
-------------------
key      value       
'a'      'apple'     
'b'      'ball'
'c'       null
'd'       ''
```

I need to PIVOT in below way  ! Key for `e` and `f` are not present in test table
but I want `e` and `f` present in pivot table with value not available

I want to pivot a,b,c,d,e,f but any key value could be missing in this case `e` and `f` are missing

```
 pivot_table
 ------------------------------------
    a        b       c      d      e         f
  'apple'  'ball'  null          'N/A'     'N/A'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `PIVOT`, you can get the same effect using conditional aggregation to check if there are 0 matching rows for each pivot key and return your default value else return the pivot value:

```sql
SELECT CASE COUNT(CASE key WHEN 'a' THEN 1 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'N/A'
       ELSE MAX(CASE key WHEN 'a' THEN value END)
       END AS a,
       CASE COUNT(CASE key WHEN 'b' THEN 1 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'N/A'
       ELSE MAX(CASE key WHEN 'b' THEN value END)
       END AS b,
       CASE COUNT(CASE key WHEN 'c' THEN 1 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'N/A'
       ELSE MAX(CASE key WHEN 'c' THEN value END)
       END AS c,
       CASE COUNT(CASE key WHEN 'd' THEN 1 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'N/A'
       ELSE MAX(CASE key WHEN 'd' THEN value END)
       END AS d,
       CASE COUNT(CASE key WHEN 'e' THEN 1 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'N/A'
       ELSE MAX(CASE key WHEN 'e' THEN value END)
       END AS e,
       CASE COUNT(CASE key WHEN 'f' THEN 1 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'N/A'
       ELSE MAX(CASE key WHEN 'f' THEN value END)
       END AS f
FROM   test_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (key, value) AS
SELECT 'a', 'apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'ball'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', NULL    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', ''      FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: In Oracle, an empty string `''` is identical to `NULL` so your `d` column will never have `''` inserted, it will contain `NULL` the same as `c`.*

Outputs:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | ball | *null* | *null* | N/A | N/A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/la_h-MyM)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following in PySpark:

- Importing modules for PySpark, for creating a Spark application and `StringType`, `StructType`, and `StructField` for defining the schema of a DataFrame.
- A sample (**smpl_data**) with two columns ('**key**' and '**value**') and a schema (**smp_schema**) specifying the data types for each column.
- Creating a PySpark DataFrame named **dilip_test_df** using the provided sample data and schema.
- Creating another DataFrame named additional_df with some additional data.
- The union operation is used to combine the two DataFrames (**dilip_test_df** and **additional_df**) into a new DataFrame named **dilip_combined_df**.
- Next, grouping the combined DataFrame by a dummy key and then pivoting the data using the 'key' values as columns. The aggregation function used is first, which takes the first non-null value.
- Then, missing values in specific columns ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f') are filled with the string '**N/A**'.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField
smpl_data = [('a', 'apple'),
             ('b', 'ball'),
             ('c', None),
             ('d', '')]
smp_schema = StructType([
    StructField("key", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value", StringType(), True)
])
dilip_test_df = spark.createDataFrame(smpl_data, schema=smp_schema)
additional_data = [('e', None), ('f', None)]
additional_df = spark.createDataFrame(additional_data, schema=smp_schema)
dilip_combined_df = dilip_test_df.union(additional_df)
dilip_pivoted_df = (dilip_combined_df
                    .groupBy()
                    .pivot("key", ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
                    .agg({"value": "first"}))
dilip_pivoted_df = dilip_pivoted_df.na.fill('N/A', subset=['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
dilip_pivoted_df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-----+----+----+---+---+---+
|a    |b   |c   |d  |e  |f  |
+-----+----+----+---+---+---+
|apple|ball|NULL|   |N/A|N/A|
+-----+----+----+---+---+---+
```

Comment: The question is not tagged with Python or Pyspark so this answer does not seem to be relevant to the OP's requirements.